# how to map an array's element with an address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

i need to store an array's element with an address. How can i do that in solidity?\

example:

```
uint balance[10];

mapping (address => balance[i]) value;

value[any adrress] = balance[8];
```

How can I do this in solidity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in solidity the exact way you mentioned it, you will need to initialize the array first like this so that you get data in the array or it will be filled with Zeros:

```
uint balance[10] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

you can also fill the array like this too:

```
balance[0] = 1;
balance[1] = 2;
```

But you can't use `balance.push()` since the array is static.